# Facebook invite- Rarely invitation gets delivered after many hours

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have done the task on "Inviting users to the app using facebook" in android, used the below codes as a result if i send the invitation, the invite message rarely delivers after many hours and or else not getting delivered, do anybody know the solution for this?

```
final ImageView facebook1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebook1);
        facebook1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){


            Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook( APP_ID );

            Bundle params = new Bundle();

            params.putString("message", "Prova ");
            mFacebook.dialog(Singlemenuitem.this, "apprequests", params, new DialogListener() {
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                                toast.show();
                                            }

                                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(),
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }

                                            public void onCancel() {
                                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App request cancelled",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                                toast.show();
                                            }

                                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            }
                                        });
              } });
```

Comment: I think that's not the application issue, but rather Facebook latency.

Comment: but most of the times my invitation doesnt get delivered, wat shud i do to make it done?